# http java call which goes wrong

Tags: java, weblogic12c

I have a java application on Weblogic 12, i make an https call to a SAP server in REST (GET e basic authentication), everything works for 30/45 minutes but after i have "503: Service Unavailable". If I call this service from browser it always works.

```
HttpURLConnection  conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL( url.toString()).openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authUserEnc);
    ... //read the response stream
    conn.disconnect();
```

this is the error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Response: '503: Service Unavailable' for url: 'https://fwp-as3.enelint.global:44331/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZFIOI_O1_Q006_SRV/ZFIOI_O1_Q006(ZVAR_VDMCUI_OI_M='0000022077',ZVAR_VDMCUI_OI_MTo='0000022077')/Results?saml2=disabled'
        at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:829)
        at weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(SOAPHttpsURLConnection.java:42)
        at it.exprivia.bexboard.service.impl.VendorServiceImpl.getData(VendorServiceImpl.java:125)
        at it.exprivia.bexboard.controller.GrafxController.getVendorGrafxById(GrafxController.java:166)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor211.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:181)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:97)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:202)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:101)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
        at ...
```

Comment: Sounds like you are being rate limited. How many times do you call the rest API from that same application per hour? What happens if you call fewer times?

Comment: about 2 calls are made per minute, if less calls are made this time increases. does weblogic have any kind of cache?

Comment: It's not a matter of cache. It sounds like a quota set on the SAP side (limit on number of requests from the same origin).

Comment: if I restart the weblogic it works for the usual time and after i have the error.